# Can not uninstall redis-server in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, redis

I was trying to install Redis on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt install redis-server
```

The process partially installed and timed-out and the redis-service was not installed.

After that I tried to remove the installation:

```
sudo apt remove redis-server
```

and still the uninstall is hanging (over 30 minutes) and not progressing:

```
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  redis-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 202 not upgraded.
After this operation, 919 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 300372 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing redis-server (2:3.0.6-1ubuntu0.3) ...
```

Is there a way to remove this package other that using `apt-get`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How to force remove when post-installation script always fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48014/how-force-remove-when-post-installation-script-always-fail)
on Ask Ubuntu.  In short, try

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all {package name}
```